# pyqtgraph: completely clear PlotWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

I am basically using the code from this example: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/MultiplePlotAxes.py but I am adding and removing the additional axes during runtime. Before adding multiple axes to my code I used pw.clear to clear the PlotWidget, but that only clears Items on axis 1. How can I completely reset the PlotWidget (including the legend)? (Without closing it and creating a new one - if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was answering Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71175650/pyqtgraph-add-items-from-seperate-viewbox-to-legend/71182931#71182931), so I will just add code snippet to do what You want. Again, `pw.clear()` would work just fine, but You have this special case with directly using `scene()`. So again, You have to do things manually.

To clear all plots and legend, You can use:

```
for plot_item in [legend, p1, p2, p3]:
    plot_item.clear()
```

You mentioned, that You are adding and removing plots dynamically. In that case, I would create a list of active plots with reset function. Then You can just add or remove curves from this list and always have consistent method to clear them all.

For example:

```
active_plot_items = [legend, p1, p2, p3]

def clear_plot_items():
    for plot_item in active_plot_items:
        plot_item.clear()

clear_plot_items()
```